# Pass id of element to ng-class directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I look all over but couldn't find a way to get id of element that has 
a `ng-class` passed to ng-class function:

```
<ol ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
     <li id="IdIWant" ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(WHAT GOES HERE?)}"></li>
     <li id="IdIWant2" ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(WHAT GOES HERE?)}"></li>
     <li id="IdIWant3" ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(WHAT GOES HERE?)}"></li>
</ol>
```

and javascript:

```
app.controller("PanelController", function(){
        this.selectTab = function(setTab){
            this.tab  = setTab;
        };
            this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
                console.log(checkTab);
                return this.tab===checkTab;
            }
        });
```

**Long story**:
In tutorials i get:

```
<li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(1)}">1</li>
<li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(2)}">2</li>
<li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(3)}">3</li>
```

then i can set active class based on the number but i want pass
number (1,2 or 3) from the id, or ng-data or other way (thus not writing it in `panel.isSelected()`)
like:

```
<li id="1" ng-data="1" ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(WHAT GOES HERE?)}">1</li>
```

Comment: Why do you need id, You just have one `li` inside a div. It is invalid html. Please showus your complete relevant code.

Comment: It would also be helpful to tell us what you're trying to accomplish here. It seems whatever it is, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Your list items are already defined by you. You are not looping over a list of items anyway so you just the type id there: `ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected('1')}"`.

Comment: I could hard code them to inside of `isSelected`. The question is how to not hardcode it but get it from the attribute of element.

Comment: @Jask why would you do this? Are you dynamically creating the HTML for these `<li>`? Are you not "hardcoding" the ids on them anyway? P.S. that's still invalid HTML. `<li>` belong inside of `<ol>` or `<ul>` not `<div>`.

Comment: @Antiga The reasoning behind that is that if i would change for example `id` of element then it would be passed to ng-class, otherwise i would have to change both `id` and the argument in function. Hope i wrote it more clear.

Comment: @Jask your question is clear but the real intent is not. I am trying to help you think about this in a different way. Can you give me the use-case of you needing to change the `id` of one of these elements?

Comment: @Antiga I think of code readability and reusage . It would be useful for, for example, copying one element and not worrying if the new element has changed hard coded values.

Comment: @Jask Why can't you use ng-repeat o li's, that will keep stuffs dry and approach in a more angular way. You can generate ids and you actually wont even need it in that case, and using ng-class to set active just gets really simple. Check out this [simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696932/apply-logic-to-every-element-in-an-ng-repeat-upon-ng-click-angularjs/27697261#27697261)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it in a different way and a more angular way. Set up the view model for the panels for example:-

Controller that set up panels:

```
.controller("PanelController", function() {

      var selectedTab;

      /*Set up the panels*/
      this.panels = [{
        id: 'panel1',
        text: 'Panel1'
      }, {
        id: 'panel2',
        text: 'Panel2'
      }, {
        id: 'panel3',
        text: 'Panel3'
      }];

      /*Set Default tab*/
      selectedTab = this.panels[0];


      this.selectTab = function(tab) {
        selectedTab = tab;
      };

      this.isSelected = function(tab) {
        return angular.equals(selectedTab, tab);
      }
    });
```

View with an ng-repeat, evethough this shows id you wouldn't need it at all. However you could set up id, either from the view model or even hardcode something and add index using `$index` property of ng-repeat, with `ng-attr-id`. `ng-class` just as you did just except for implementation. For brevity added an ng-click. Though it is not clear where it is coming from based on your example code in the question (If you clarify this can be adjusted as required).:

```
   <li ng-repeat="pnl in panelCtrl.panels track by pnl.id" 
       ng-attr-id="{{pnl.id}}" 
       ng-class="{active: panelCtrl.isSelected(pnl)}" 
       ng-click="panelCtrl.selectTab(pnl)">{{pnl.text}}</li>
```

**Sample Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller("PanelController", function() {

  var selectedTab;

  /*Set up the panels*/
  this.panels = [{
    id: 'panel1',
    text: 'Panel1'
  }, {
    id: 'panel2',
    text: 'Panel2'
  }, {
    id: 'panel3',
    text: 'Panel3'
  }];

  /*Default tab*/
  selectedTab = this.panels[0];


  this.selectTab = function(tab) {
    selectedTab = tab;
  };

  this.isSelected = function(tab) {
    return selectedTab === tab;
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
  font-size: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ol ng-controller="PanelController as panelCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="pnl in panelCtrl.panels track by pnl.id" ng-attr-id="{{pnl.id}}" ng-class="{active: panelCtrl.isSelected(pnl)}" ng-click="panelCtrl.selectTab(pnl)">{{pnl.text}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```